# How to achieve High Availability for web service?

Tags: web-services, high-availability

May I know how to achieve this, Assuming I have 2 ips to call my web service on a server, do I assign primary, and secondary dns,one pointing to first ip, the other pointing to second ip?

Comment: Is this related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257969/is-it-possible-that-one-domain-name-has-multiple-corresponding-ip-addresses

Comment: would like to know what is the recommended practice for this,according to the practice above, if one web service is down, it will not "failover" to the second web service. It will just make random calls to the first IP and the second IP. Since the first IP is down, it will return failure for the web service. So if one of the web service source is down, this means the web service is available 50% of the time

Answer (score 0):

have a look at below link, this may be helpful https://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/configuration/front-end-proxy-and-software-load-balancing