# why do domains like Google have so many IPs?

Tags: c#, dns, network-programming

I am writing some code to retrieve IPs from a domain that comes from a querystring. To achieve this, I have used

```
Dns.GetHostAddresses(uri);
```

Which return type is a array of `System.Net.IPAddress[]`

But I want to write a comment in the code to explain to the developer why a domain such as google for example, may (OK google will) return more than 1 IP address.

Does anyone have a definition or can direct me to a website that has material on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its used as a kind of 'load balancer' for DNS queries.

See here for a good discussion:

[Is it possible that one domain name has multiple corresponding IP addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257969/is-it-possible-that-one-domain-name-has-multiple-corresponding-ip-addresses)